# How to retrieve query stored in session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, session

while using codeigniter i have saved current query in session so that I can show pagination in detail page means prev/next button detail screen.But when I use LIKE %10% in query it shows in home page that its stored in session but when I go to detail page its not in the session.Any guess
I am not storing session in database as documented in [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

my query is simple

```
SELECT Contac.cm_id 
FROM Contact 
LEFT JOIN Employer 
    ON (Contact.c_id = Employer.ei_contact_id) 
        AND (Employer.ei_primary_employer = "Y")
WHERE ( Contact.cm_staff_name LIKE '%s%' 
    AND Contact.cm_staff_name NOT LIKE 'NULL' ) 
ORDER BY Contact.cm_id ASC
```

so when there is 03 in `Contact.cm_staff_name LIKE '%03%'` its not passing that query from one page to another through session .
Also please suggest if better solution instead of using session.
Any guess

Comment: Maybe a typo but the table name in the field list reads Contac

Comment: @Orangepill yes its printing mistake.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in storing *a program* anywhere.
A program have to be written in a constant form and fed with dynamical *variables*.

Using sessions for pagination is also wrong idea - look at google for example - they always use a query string to pass variables for the next page. It will let a user to bookmark certain page or send it to a friend or whatever. It is **always a pain** when a friend sends you a link but you have no their session and cannot see what they see.

So, write your query right in the code
pass all the variables via GET query string
and use *prepared statements* to insert variables into query